# Animate UIView which follows touch but is attached to a certain point

Tags: objective-c, core-animation, avfoundation

I am trying to make an animation. It's quite difficult to explain what I'm trying to achieve as seen on the title of my post.

So here's how I describe what I want to do...

1. Please imagine a clock with just one hand..
2. When the user swipes to left but does not release the touch, the hand would animate/rotate to the left..
3. While still holding on the touch, if the user swipes to right, then the hand would rotate to the right .. 
   On number's 2 and 3.. we should not forget that the hand's anchor point is at the bottom...

Basically, if the user swipes to the left, then the hand would rotate to the left, then if the user moves back the touch to the middle, then the hand would go back to its original place.

In other words, what I'm trying to achieve is, the hand clock should follow the touch of the user while the touch is held.. all these happening while the hand clock still attached to its anchor point.. basically, what i want is similar to the behavior of a real world clock which follows touch direction...

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: First, i would like to apologize since my post is very vague.. I just have no idea at all how I would implement this or what I should use.. Core animation or UIView animation..
PS.. I have little knowledge of Core Animation..
thanks again

Comment: For others who are looking for what I am looking for as well..

http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2012/02/13/an-one-finger-rotation-gesture-recognizer/

i am trying to follow the link above .. another tutorial I found that could be helpful would be http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, seeing as you've said you have little knowledge of Core Animatiom that you are using `UIView`s to achive this, not `CALayer`s? If so it might be a good idea to look at the [CALayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/index.html) class as it has a useful little property called `anchorPoint`.

This anchor point is the "control point" which Core Animation will then use to calculate any animation, i.e if you set the anchor point to the bottom left hand corner of the layer and add a rotation animation you will ge the behaviour you're looking for.

Using CoreAnimation the code would look a bit like this:

```
myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0);

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
anim.fromValue = @(myView.layer.transform.rotation.z)
anim.toValue = @(//enter desired angle here in radians)
anim.duration = //duration
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;

[myView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"rotate"];

myView.layer.transform.rotation.z = // desired angle
```

***NOTE: I haven't tested this code, it's just to get you started.***

To convert degrees to radians, you take the degree divide by 180 and times by M_PI (a constant). e.g. `#define DEG_TO_RAD(deg)((deg / 180) * M_PI)` is the standard macro which you can use like this: `float radians = DEG_TO_RAD(90.0f);`

If you want the "clock hand" to **track** the user's finger (as opposed to swipe and rotate) then you might be better off NOT using animations and simply incrementally changing the `transform` of your view's layer using `-touchesMoved:.....` to track the angle.

There is a LOT more to get through when it comes to this subject so check out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) and [this](http://sketchytech.blogspot.com.es/2014/12/explaining-catransform3d-matrix.html).

Comment: thanks..  will get back to this thread as soon as i finish making it